# Custom http Headers vs https. Which is best in this scenario?

Tags: apache, http, https, http-headers

I don't want to leave any chance for hackers to see what I put in URI apart form the domain. For example,

http://www.mynewwebsite.com/ (some text or webpage.html)

In the above, I want to make '(some text or webpage.html)' secure

Now I am confused between two approaches.

1) Should I add a custom http header whose value is "(some text or webpage.html)" and on the server, I read the header to address the request.

2) Should I simply switch to https?

What are the pros and cons of each? (Forget about additional money i need to pay to use https)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HTTPS is free, mate. https://letsencrypt.org/ Any hacker who can intercept the URL can intercept your custom headers too, if it's over HTTP. Use HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to https is simple solution if you don't want hackers to sniff your network and read request params

Answer (score 1):

With HTTPS, the request and headers are encrypted, this should prevent prying eyes as per your requirements. Depending upon your setup, the SSL certificate may be free using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org).

If you simply add a custom header to an HTTP request, you may hide your intentions from a cursory glance but the data could still be accessible to a 3rd party.

Comment: The on ly issue is that the full URL may end up in the server logs.

Comment: This is true but if you can't trust your server then no amount of security on top will lead to a trustworthy system as you are already compromised.

Comment: Sometimes the stats will display the path and query string information. To many people may have access, there may be poor login security such as not using 2-factor authentication. Also you should not trust the server, that is how most attacks occur, an attacker gains admin access possibly via spear-fishing or a server not up to date on patches and a privilege escalation flaw. That is why passwords should never be saved on the server and a secure password verifier needs to be used that takes ~100ms.

Comment: A couple of top examples: [RSA](https://www.rsa.com/en-us) lost token seeds and [Gemalto](http://www.gemalto.com) lost a signing key. You would would expect companies at this level of security would not be vulnerable. RSA fell to a spear-fishing attack simple and escalated the gained access. Be paranoid, it works!

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Should I add a custom http header whose value is "(some text or
>   webpage.html)" and on the server, I read the header to address the
>   request.

I think you misunderstood how http works. The header content are sent before the body content. The hacker could simply read the entire stream and focuses on just the header to extract information.

> 2) Should I simply switch to https?

Switching to HTTPS is a must (to me) if you are going to do user authentication or wanting to keep something secret. It encrypts the information so unintended recipients cannot understand. The recipient have to decide that information with their private key.

There are a number of SSL options that you have.

> lets encrypt
>   It's the biggest free ssl certificate provider. However their certs only have a 3 months life so you need to renew it every now and then. Perhaps you can look up `cron` job and use it to check with let's encrypt server and renew when expire date near.

Other paid ssl provider
Although both has no differ in encryption level. But features that standout between the two that lets encrypt yet to have is wildcard ssl on *.yoururl.com. This offers the entire sub domain not just a single url as well as in an event of breach, insurance will cover for the damage.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS encrypts your payload (including headers and URL via SSL/TLS) along the route from point A to point B, preventing hackers from seeing your data if they intercept it between these two points. It's the only way to achieve the security you're looking for.

However if the potential hacker legally sits at point B, HTTPS will not help you.  Regardless if the information is tucked away in the header or part of the URL, it will be visible.  Anyone can see the headers. If you want to hide specific information from the end-user, manually encrypt it.